# Sencha 2: Listeners on a panel not working

Tags: events, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to port my Sencha app from Sencha1 to Sencha2.

It seems that none of my listeners are working.  The documentation for Sencha2 seems to have different events, and a smaller number of events:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.Panel

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Panel

Is there a new way to do this? Are the listeners from Sencha1 just not implemented in Sencha2 yet?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Loading', {
        extend: 'Ext.Panel',
        googleAnalyticsName: 'Loading',
        id: 'loadingView',
        xtype: 'loading',
        config: {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            scrollable: false,
            items: [{
                html: '<div id="loading-view" style="background-repeat: none;"><div id="loading-page-spinner"></div>'
            }],
            listeners: {
                activate: function() {
                    console.log('activate listener');
                },
                afterrender: function() {
                    console.log('afterrender listener')             
                }
            },
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Loading', {
        extend: 'Ext.Panel',
        googleAnalyticsName: 'Loading',
        id: 'loadingView',
        xtype: 'loading',
        initialize: function() {

            this.on('activate', function() { alert('activate'); } );

            this.callParent();
        }
    ...
```